# How to display the number of posts in a category using WP Query

Tags: wp-query

Just a quick one but I am stuck in doing this. I am running a WP_Query for a category and and want to know how to display the number of posts in a category using WP Query!

This is the start of my WP_query but how to I just simply echo out the number of posts in this category?! It is driving me mad!

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'cat' => 33,
    'posts_per_page' => 500,
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>


<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :?> 


    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`found_posts` property](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Properties), which is the **total** number posts for the current query:

```
echo $the_query->found_posts;
```

Comment: Perfect thanks for that, I will mark as the answer  - have a great day :)